# How do i aggregate by using field names as buckets in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have multiple documents with different fields in each doc. There are some similar fields in some docs but there are some that are different. Is it possible to have aggregations with theses different field names as buckets?

I don't even know how to attempt this as all the examples I saw special a field to do aggregations on.

Basically I want the response to look like:

```
{
  ...
  "aggregations": {
    "genres": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,   
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,           
      "buckets": [                        
        {
          "key": "field_1",
          "doc_count": 6
        },
        {
          "key": "field_2",
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": "field_3",
          "doc_count": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

An example document looks like this:

```
   {
      "_index" : "responses",
      "_type" : "_doc",
      "_id" : "SdFHc34BUp9LLqFf9Ta2",
      "_version" : 1,
      "_seq_no" : 382344,
      "_primary_term" : 2,
      "found" : true,
      "_source" : {
        "respid" : 25731,
        "respStatus" : 3,
        "cqHidCountry" : 1,
        "field_1" : 32,
        "field_2" : 2,
        "field_3" : 1,
        "market" : "us"
        "date" : "2020-01-01"
    }
```

Other documents are similar and can have different different fields:

```
       {
          "_index" : "responses",
          "_type" : "_doc",
          "_id" : "SdFHc34BUp9LLqFf9Ta2",
          "_version" : 1,
          "_seq_no" : 382344,
          "_primary_term" : 2,
          "found" : true,
          "_source" : {
            "field_1" : 32,
            "field_4" : 2,
            "field_6" : 1,
            "market" : "us"
            "date" : "2020-04-01"
        }
```

Mappings and dynamic as we add documents and look like this:

```
{
  "responses" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "field_1" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "field_2" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "field_3" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "market" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          },
          "fielddata" : true
        },
        "field_4" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "field_6" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "date" : {
          "type" : "date"
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add your mapping and an example document

Comment: @ilvar i added some more edits, hope it helps!